# java.util.Date null with ProGuard

Tags: java, android, gson, proguard, java.util.date

**Project:**
https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample

When I run the app in the `Development_Debug` Build Flavor, the model
[Movie.java](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daksh/tmdbsample/data/model/Movie.java)
returns a non-null Date object, and thus its processing using `DataBinding`
[here](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daksh/tmdbsample/data/model/Movie.java#L151)
works fine. The `TextView` is populated with a formatted date string.

However, when I run the app with the exact same code in the `Development_Release` Build Flavor with [`minifyEnabled true`](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L51-L51),
the app crashes with a `NullPointerException` with the following stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.daksh.tmdbsample, PID: 10470
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1197)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:527)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:829)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
    at com.daksh.tmdbsample.data.model.Movie.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.daksh.tmdbsample.databinding.MovieDetailBinding.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$5.onViewAttachedToWindow(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Additionally, this crash *does not* occur when I add the `-dontobfuscate` rule to my
[proguard-rules.pro](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro).

Please help me resolve this crash (I don't want to add `-dontobfuscate` to my ProGuard rules).

Which ProGuard rules shall I add? Probably something for Gson and java.util.Date?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this syntactic sugar in `Movie.java` stops working:

```
@BindingAdapter({"releaseDate"})
```

Your either need to rewrite the code or make an exception in proguard for this class.

Comment: However, other usages of `@BindingAdapter` work perfectly fine with `ProGuard` enabled.

See [here](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daksh/tmdbsample/data/model/Movie.java#L100) and [here](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/daksh/tmdbsample/data/model/Movie.java#L109).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a **BindingAdapter** for a field (releaseDate) that gets obfuscated. This will not work and you will need to keep this field non-obfuscated. My suggestion would be to add the following:

```
-keep class com.daksh.tmdbsample.data.model.Movie {
    private final java.util.Date releaseDate;
}
```

If you have more cases where you need to keep the field names non-obfuscated, I would suggest to use annotations to keep such fields with a rule like that (assuming you use the @SerializedName annotation on them):

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

Comment: I use `@SerializedName` only for fields whose names are different from their keys in JSON Strings.

So I guess I'll have to check each field and add rules as per your first suggestion.

Comment: Using \@SerializedName was just a suggestion. If you do not want to use it you might also take a look at the \@Keep annotation from the Android support annotations library: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations